# How to make the blue line in this diagram red?

Tags: colors, adobe-photoshop, diagrams

How to make the blue line in this diagram red?

[image]

Comment: 1. The legend shows two series, but the chart contains only one, and the color is the values for the series that was plotted.  If you change the color to that of the other series or no listed series, it will still be missing a series, and the line will reflect the wrong series or be unidentified.  2. The place to manipulate a chart is in the software that created it.  Manipulating a picture of the result is a lot messier.  3. If you need to do it in Photoshop, sample the line color and use that to select the line based on matching the color in a contiguous area.  Replace it with the new color.

Answer (score 1):

Hue/Saturation adjustment **Image > Adjustments > Hue/Saturation**. Rotate the hue 60° or maybe -60°, or whatever until it's the right colour.

Note that it will also rotate the hue of the green dot. To avoid this, either:

- marquee a selection over the blue parts (you don't have to be super accurate, because the black and white parts of the image have zero saturation it won't affect them), or
- in the Hue Sat panel choose just blues or cyans (you may have to fiddle with the range selector, the first method is probably easier for noobs).